# How do I stop Wordpress dashboard widgets from being dragged?

Tags: wordpress, drag-and-drop, widget, dashboard, add-filter

I'm setting up Wordpress 3.0.1 for a novice user. The Dashboard widgets are appropriately placed, and I'd like them to stay that way. As far as I know, there's no add_filter or add_action hook to prevent dragging, so another approach would be to make a plugin that uses jQuery to disable dragging. What handler(s) would I override -- click, mouseUp, mouseMove, etc -- and on which DOM elements?

Comment: Is there a reason the user needs access to the Appearance settings? Can you just limit the users access to the themes and widgets all together?

Comment: They don't have access to Appearance; they're Authors. The only widgets I left on the Dashboard are Right Now and Quickpress. I just want to disable dragging and dropping those widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the easiest thing to do is prevent the new order from being saved. This will let the user change the order, but it won't save the changes for the next time the page is loaded.

You want to prevent the `meta-box-order` ajax event:

```
add_action('check_ajax_referer', 'prevent_meta_box_order');
function prevent_meta_box_order($action)
{
    if ('meta-box-order' == $action /* && $wp_user == 'santa claus' */) {
        die('-1');
    }
}
```

There are probably other actions you want to prevent too. Open Firebug and check out which requests to `admin-ajax.php` are made when you do stuff that you would like to prevent. Or hide the *Screen Options* tab with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent loading the script that handles the widget/metabox dragging and collapsing behaviour:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', function() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'postbox' );
} );
```

Optionally combine it with some CSS to hide the arrow icon and dragging cursor since this functionality is now disabled:

```
.handlediv {
    display: none !important;
}
.hndle, .widget-top {
    cursor: default !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Roles plugin like [WordPress › Role Scoper « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) to restrict what the user can do. Not a good idea to edit core files, as your changes will get overwritten on upgrade.

Comment: I didn't find any capabilities related to dragging and dropping the widgets. Thanks though.

Comment: On second thought, widgets are a core WP thing, so yea, might have to hack core files.